# Importing off-line conversion data in to Google Analytics - can'[t select metrics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to import data in to analytics. When I select the "User Data type" it allows me to set user ID as the key, but then I can't select any metrics? Screen here

http://content.screencast.com/users/KJPH/folders/Jing/media/b0905e94-7e2f-49a4-8c63-5cbacb8f22cb/2015-05-15_0836.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first create user scoped custom dimensions. See this complete example of [how to import user data into Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4524584?hl=en#step_two_create_the_custom_dimension).

Comment: Thanks. What I want to do is import offline conversions. Just a simple counter for a unique goal and attach it to user ids. Would this be a workable approach? My other thought is to have a script read the file and send the conversions via measurement protocol...do you know if it's a good or bad idea? We are as of now limited to receiving the sales data in weekly batches.